# Django - Generic detail view DailyForecastDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Can someone assist me with this? I am new to Django and am apparently missing a connection between my code somewhere. I already tried some of the sollutions mentioned on SOF for this problem, but I can't get it working.

I get the error:

Generic detail view DailyForecastDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

On my local url with date (http://127.0.0.1:8000/forecast/narnia/2023-03-26/) and without the date parameter (http://127.0.0.1:8000/forecast/narnia/)

**
models.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


# Create your models here.
class DefaultProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    bio = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__} object for {self.user}"


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    timezone_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "locations"


# class CurrentWeather(models.Model):


class Forecast(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="forecasts")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class DailyForecast(Forecast):
    date = models.DateField()
    date_epoch = models.IntegerField()
    maxtemp_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    maxtemp_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    mintemp_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    mintemp_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    avgtemp_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    avgtemp_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    maxwind_mph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    maxwind_kph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    totalprecip_mm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    totalprecip_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    avgvis_km = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    avgvis_miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    avghumidity = models.IntegerField()
    daily_will_it_rain = models.IntegerField()
    daily_will_it_snow = models.IntegerField()
    daily_chance_of_rain = models.IntegerField()
    daily_chance_of_snow = models.IntegerField()
    uv = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.location.name}, {self.date}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "daily forecasts"


class HourlyForecast(Forecast):
    time_epoch = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    temp_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    temp_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    is_day = models.BooleanField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.IntegerField()
    wind_mph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    wind_kph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    wind_degree = models.IntegerField()
    wind_dir = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pressure_mb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    pressure_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    precip_mm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    precip_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    humidity = models.IntegerField()
    cloud = models.IntegerField()
    feelslike_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    feelslike_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    windchill_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    windchill_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    heatindex_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    heatindex_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    dewpoint_c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    dewpoint_f = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    will_it_rain = models.IntegerField()
    will_it_snow = models.IntegerField()
    vis_km = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vis_miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    chance_of_rain = models.IntegerField()
    chance_of_snow = models.IntegerField()
    gust_mph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    gust_kph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    uv = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.location.name}, {self.time}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "hourly forecasts"
```

**
views.py**:

```
from datetime import date

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, TemplateView

from .models import DailyForecast, HourlyForecast, Location


class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "forecast/daily_forecast_detail.html"


class LocationListView(ListView):
    model = Location
    template_name = "forecast/location_list.html"
    context_object_name = "locations"


class DailyForecastDetailView(DetailView):
    model = DailyForecast
    template_name = "forecast/daily_forecast_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "forecast"

    def get_queryset(self):
        location_slug = self.kwargs["location_slug"]
        date = self.kwargs["date"]
        location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=location_slug)
        return DailyForecast.objects.filter(location=location, date=date)


class DailyForecastTodayView(DetailView):
    model = DailyForecast
    template_name = "forecast/daily_forecast_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "forecast"

    def get_queryset(self):
        location_slug = self.kwargs["location_slug"]
        location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=location_slug)
        date_today = date.today()
        return DailyForecast.objects.filter(location=location, date=date_today)


class HourlyForecastDetailView(DetailView):
    model = HourlyForecast
    template_name = "forecast/hourly_forecast_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "forecast"

    def get_queryset(self):
        location_slug = self.kwargs["location_slug"]
        date = self.kwargs["date"]
        hour = self.kwargs["hour"]
        location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=location_slug)
        return HourlyForecast.objects.filter(location=location, date=date, hour=hour)
```

**
urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    BaseView,
    DailyForecastDetailView,
    DailyForecastTodayView,
    HourlyForecastDetailView,
    LocationListView,
)

app_name = "forecast"

urlpatterns = [
    # path("", LocationListView.as_view(), name="location_list"),
    path("<slug:location_slug>/<date>/", DailyForecastDetailView.as_view(), name="daily_forecast_detail"),
    path("<slug:location_slug>/", DailyForecastTodayView.as_view(), name="daily_forecast_today"),
    # path("", BaseView.as_view(), name="daily_forecast_detail"),
    path("<slug:location_slug>/<date>/<int:hour>/", HourlyForecastDetailView.as_view(), name="hourly_forecast_detail"),
]
```

On my local machine I accessed the following temp url with date (http://127.0.0.1:8000/forecast/narnia/2023-03-26/) and without the date parameter (http://127.0.0.1:8000/forecast/narnia/) and I get the error:

Generic detail view DailyForecastDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error, detail view expect a `pk` or `slug` url parameter to achieve

```
MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

or

```
MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

If the unique key in your case is the `date`, your code should look something like

```
class DailyForecastDetailView(DetailView):
    model = DailyForecast
    template_name = "forecast/daily_forecast_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "forecast"
    slug_field = "date"
    slug_url_kwarg = "date"

    def get_queryset(self):
        location_slug = self.kwargs["location_slug"]
        location = get_object_or_404(Location, slug=location_slug)
        return DailyForecast.objects.filter(location=location)
```